# How to select table name dynamically in Linq or Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I want to call controller method for data in that there can be multiple data output from different table so it depends on user selection from which table they wanna to take output and so i was thinking to get output using single linq just by passed name of table according to user selection.

```
           query = (from Ledger in fen.TblLedgers
                     join acc in fen.Accounts
                     on Ledger.Code equals acc.AccId
                     where acc.DrCr == Fin.DRCR && Ledger.Grp == Fin.LedGrp  && acc.Vdate <= DateTime.Today && Ledger.isActive == "Y" group acc by new { acc.AccId } into g select g.Sum(acc => acc.Amt)).Sum() ;
```

Comment: You can't. Not out of the box, its techically possible, but you need to mess with `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`s. Not easy. However it sounds like a code smell to me, wanting to dynamically select the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, one approach would be to use lambdas and implement something like the below.

Long and short of it - you'd need to leverage the DbContext.Set < T > method [DbContext.Set method (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx) or [the generic one (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.113).aspx)

Vary T (or the type parameter) by the users choice, and then lambda from there.

However, in order to do this, all T's would need to implement the same interface and you'd need to cast the elements to that interface before using them. But, you'd have to do this if you want any of this stuff to work at all...)

(Code below written freehand, don't complain if there's the odd mistake!)

So - with classes:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    ....
}
public class Dog :IAnimal
{
    ....
}
public class Cat :IAnimal
{
    ....
}
public class Cow :IAnimal
{
    ...
}
```

You could use something like:

```
var userSelection = "Dog";
Type chosenType = chooseTypeAccordingToUserSelection(userSelection);
var animalDBSet = GetOpenDBcontext().Set(chosenType).Cast<IAnimal>();
var insects = animalDBSet.Where(a=>a.NumberOfLegs>4);
```

HTH!